# How do you reference another GWT project in your project?

Tags: smartgwt

I have a SmartGWT project up and running. Now, I would like to create a new project SmartGWT which has to launch the servlet of the previous SmartGWT project. Is this possible?

**EDIT :**

Let's say your second GWT module wants to call methods from the first GWT Module; What are the steps to do that?

Comment: What does "has to launch the servlet" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was rather simple and straight forward.
When you want to call the other service, you do it just like you do it as if you were in the same project by creating the service as follows:

```
OtherModuleServiceAsync otherModuleService = GWT.create(OtherModuleService.class)
```

Also, you should add the servlet mapping of the OtherModule in this module so that it can call the other service.